# Pywinauto timings waiting 0.5 seconds instead of immediate

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

I have the following Pywinauto code and timings waiting is 0.5 seconds instead of immediate. How to get itimmediately?

- To click a button and go to the next message:

```
from pywinauto import application, timings, mouse
import time

app = application.Application()
app.connect(title = 'Mensagem')
app = app.Mensagem
app2 = app.TBPanel2
buttonCoord = int((app2.rectangle().right - app2.rectangle().left)/2/2), int((app2.rectangle().bottom - app2.rectangle().top)/2)
buttonCoord = buttonCoord[0]*(2*2-1),buttonCoord[1]
timings.Timings.after_clickinput_wait = 0.001
timings.Timings.after_setcursorpos_wait = 0.001

starttime = time.perf_counter()
#while app.Edit1.texts()[0] != '':
for i in range(10):
    buttonCoord = int((app2.rectangle().right - app2.rectangle().left)/2/2), int((app2.rectangle().bottom - app2.rectangle().top)/2)
    buttonCoord = buttonCoord[0]*(2*2-1),buttonCoord[1]
    app2.click_input(button='left', coords=(buttonCoord))
    print('Entre cliques demorou ', str(time.perf_counter()-starttime), ' segundos')
    starttime = time.perf_counter()
```

When I run, the interval between clicks is 0.5 seconds:

```
Entre cliques demorou  0.4614592999999999  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.44403170000000003  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.48520320000000017  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.4723533999999998  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.46825479999999997  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.4439942000000001  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.4874373999999997  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.47333040000000004  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.46036510000000064  segundos
```

However, when I move my mouse frantically, it goes faster:

```
Entre cliques demorou  0.06659199999999998  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.1532768000000001  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.05349690000000007  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.049827499999999914  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.05078930000000015  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.04885250000000019  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.06023690000000004  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.048675000000000024  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.05394080000000012  segundos
Entre cliques demorou  0.05615450000000011  segundos
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Edit: For a more generic approach and testing, tweaked code, same results

```
from pywinauto import application, timings
import time

app2 = application.Application()
app2.connect(title_re = '.*Notas*') #In portuguese, Notepad is translated to 'Bloco de Notas', so change to your system name
app2 = app2.window(title_re = '.*Notas*') #same here
app2 = app2.wrapper_object()
timings.Timings.after_clickinput_wait = 0.001
timings.Timings.after_setcursorpos_wait = 0.001
starttime = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    app2.click_input(button='left', coords=(100,100))
    print('Between clicks took ', str(time.perf_counter()-starttime), ' seconds')
    starttime = time.perf_counter()
```

Comment: Pywinauto line 5 `app.connect(title = 'Mensagem')` throws ***pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Mensagem', 'backend': 'win32', 'visible_only': False}***. What should I use to test your code? Notebook?

Comment: I am sorry I gave no explanation to the code. It checks for a window named "Mensagem", then it gets the X/Y of the button and clicks on it. You can change it to whichever window you like, and set the buttonCoord to a fixed X/Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pre-search the element `app2` and save it as wrapper object:

```
app2 = app.TBPanel2.wrapper_object()
# or
app2 = app.TBPanel2.wait('ready', timeout=10) # if you need non-default time to wait
```

In your current code `app2 = app.TBPanel2` is a `WindowSpecification` object which is just a criteria to search. So when you're calling `.rectangle()` or `.click_input()` the search procedure is called implicitly every time. This is described in the [Getting Started Guide, Chapter "Window Specification"](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#window-specification).

Also I'd recommend to name the variable `tb_panel2_spec` or `tb_panel2_wrapper` instead of `app2` to avoid confusion about its type.

P.S. Also the reliable cross-platform way to measure time in Python is `import timeit; timeit.default_timer()`.

PS2: `from pywinauto import mouse` is not necessary because you're using method `.click_input()`.

---

EDIT3:

The real problem is `win32gui.GetDoubleClickTime()` which returns 500 ms. Method `.click_input()` tries to eliminate double click this way. We can add optional parameter to disable this wait. You can workaround it by monkey patching `win32gui`. Add this code at the beginning:

```
import win32gui

def no_double_click_time():
    return 0

win32gui.GetDoubleClickTime = no_double_click_time
```

Comment: I included the `.wrapper_object()` to the app2 line, however there is no change. It is still taking .5 seconds. Removing the mouse import also did not change that

Comment: If it depends on mouse move, I'd suggest to move mouse out of screen first to avoid any attempt to show a tooltip, then do your actions. It can be done by `mouse.move(coords=(-500, 200))`.

Comment: The mouse move I said was physical mouse move. It seems like if it tries to do entirely on programming, it adds this 0.5 sec wait. Even adding a mouse.move does not skip the .5 wait

Comment: Well, the problem is here: `win32gui.GetDoubleClickTime()` which returns 500 ms. Method `.click_input()` tries to eliminate double click this way. We can add optional parameter to disable this wait. You can workaround it by monkey patching `win32gui`. I've added the workaround code to the answer.

Comment: I was going to say "You just copy-pasted the github solution so no bounty for you", but then I realized it was you all along haha. Thanks. It works

Comment: Ha-ha, I would say "GitHub reply was copy-pasted from here". :) Thanks for reporting it!

Answer (score 0):

A bug with timeouts was fixed in version `0.6.3` maybe this is the problem in your case

Comment: Thanks, but my version is 0.6.8.

Comment: @Mathix420 it would be fair to delete this answer since this is not the case for sure.